# Create DataFrame from another DataFrame.describe() - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [861166021755746, 861166021755746, 861166021755746]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Test'].describe(), columns = ['Test2'])

print(df.describe())
print(df_2.describe())
```

Here is output

```
Test
count  3.000000e+00
mean   8.611660e+14
std    0.000000e+00
min    8.611660e+14
25%    8.611660e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14
        Test2
count       0
unique      0
```

I cannot understand why output is not the same for `df` and `df_2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in how you are creating `df_2`. When you say `columns=['Test2']`, you are discarding all columns from `df['Test'].describe()` which are *not* named `Test2`. But there are no columns named `Test2`. So you throw out all columns, resulting in an empty dataframe.

To do what you'd like, provide a dictionary whose key is the new column name, `Test2`, and whose value is `df['Test'].describe()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [861166021755746, 861166021755746, 861166021755746]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Test2': df['Test'].describe()})
```

So that:

```
>>> print(df.describe())

               Test
count  3.000000e+00
mean   8.611660e+14
std    0.000000e+00
min    8.611660e+14
25%    8.611660e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14

>>> print(df_2)

              Test2
count  3.000000e+00
mean   8.611660e+14
std    0.000000e+00
min    8.611660e+14
25%    8.611660e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14
```

Answer (score 2):

You need add [`tolist()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [861166021755746, 861166021755746, 861166021755746]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Test'].describe().tolist(), columns = ['Test2'])

print(df.describe())

                Test
count  3.000000e+00
mean   8.611660e+14
std    0.000000e+00
min    8.611660e+14
25%    8.611660e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14

print(df_2.describe())

              Test2
count  8.000000e+00
mean   6.458745e+14
std    3.986424e+14
min    0.000000e+00
25%    6.458745e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14
```

And it is different, because dataframes are different:

```
print df
print df_2

              Test
0  861166021755746
1  861166021755746
2  861166021755746
          Test2
0  3.000000e+00
1  8.611660e+14
2  0.000000e+00
3  8.611660e+14
4  8.611660e+14
5  8.611660e+14
6  8.611660e+14
7  8.611660e+14
```

And if you can not use `tolist()`, you get empty  `df_2`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [861166021755746, 861166021755746, 861166021755746]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df['Test'].describe(), columns = ['Test2'])


print df
              Test
0  861166021755746
1  861166021755746
2  861166021755746

print df_2

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Test2]
Index: []
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course, they are different. I meant I expect the second one to be non-empty. Do you know why I need `tolist()`. If I use `series_test = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6])
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(series_test, columns = ['Test3'])`, then I get non-empty dataframe